# Initializing multiple (unique) entries of a vector

Tags: c++, vector

With an array you can do this:

```
int a[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 }
```

How do you do this with a vector?

Comment: You currently cannot use initializer lists with vectors, but that is a feature in C++0x, which to my knowledge has yet to be implemented in compilers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how-to initialize 'const std::vector<T>' like a c array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231491/how-to-initialize-const-stdvectort-like-a-c-array)

Comment: @Shaktal: It's certainly implemented in my (fairly old) version of GCC, as long as you enable it with `--std=c++0x`. But you're correct, it's not valid in C++03.

Comment: @Mike Ahh, I wasn't aware that it was implemented in GCC, although I do know that it's possibly the most up to date compiler out there (probably due to it's open-source nature). Thanks for clearing that up! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write this, though its not an initialization, but looks very appealing:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10; //all pushed into the vector!
```

And to support this syntax, you need two utility operators defined as:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T>& operator << (std::vector<T>& v, const T & item)
{
    v.push_back(item);  return v;
}
template<typename T>
std::vector<T>& operator,(std::vector<T>& v, const T & item)
{
    v.push_back(item);  return v;
}
```

And  you're done!

Test code:

```
int main() {
       std::vector<int> v;
       v << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10;

       for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; ++i )
             std::cout << v[i] << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Online demo : http://www.ideone.com/1hyR3

Using the utility operators, you actually can avoid temporary variables such as the one in @Als's solution,  and you can write this without boost!

Comment: looks very nice, still it doesn't work with size_t or double (error starts with `error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘v << 1’` on g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2)

Comment: @hardmooth: Use two different template parameters if you want to allow mismatched (but convertible) types.

Comment: yes, you're right. templating it to `template<typename S, typename T>
std::vector<S>& operator << (std::vector<S>& v, const T & item)` does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Boost, You can simply use **[Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html)**

```
std::vector<int> v = boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6);
```

Or

If you are not using Boost, you can do it in two steps:

```
static const int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
vector<int> v (a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use boost, you can use this:

```
std::vector<int> myvec;
int myints[] = {1776, 7, 4};
myvec.assign(myints, myints + 3);
```

Not exactly the same, but it comes very close. I always use this.

Answer (score 0):

As of C++ 11 you can create a vector object with list-initialization as follows:

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int> v2 {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

And in C++ 17 you can omit the type to allow C++ to infer the type based on the datatype passed in the list (provided you don't mix the types):

```
// C++ 17
std::vector v3 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector v4 {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Comment: Are you missing a ";" on the second line in your first code block?