# How to initialize a vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, declaration

I want to initialize a vector like we do in case of an array.

Example

```
int vv[2] = {12, 43};
```

But when I do it like this,

```
vector<int> v(2) = {34, 23};
```

OR

```
vector<int> v(2);
v = {0, 9};
```

it gives an error:

> expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token

AND

> error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘=’ token

respectively.

Comment: There's also [how-to initialize 'const std::vector<T>' like a c array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231491/how-to-initialize-const-stdvectort-like-a-c-array/254143).

Comment: You should enable C++11 support in your compiler, e.g. `g++ -std=c++11 your_file.cc`. Then you can use initializer list constructor of the thread (the last item in [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector))

Comment: Not a dupe - the other question is how to do it with old c++,  WTF's answer is how to do it now

Answer (score 291, accepted):

With the new C++ standard (may need special flags to be enabled on your compiler) you can simply do:

```
std::vector<int> v { 34,23 };
// or
// std::vector<int> v = { 34,23 };
```

Or even:

```
std::vector<int> v(2);
v = { 34,23 };
```

On compilers that don't support this feature (initializer lists) yet you can emulate this with an array:

```
int vv[2] = { 12,43 };
std::vector<int> v(&vv[0], &vv[0]+2);
```

Or, for the case of assignment to an existing vector:

```
int vv[2] = { 12,43 };
v.assign(&vv[0], &vv[0]+2);
```

Like James Kanze suggested, it's more robust to have functions that give you the beginning and end of an array:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
T* begin(T(&arr)[N]) { return &arr[0]; }
template <typename T, size_t N>
T* end(T(&arr)[N]) { return &arr[0]+N; }
```

And then you can do this without having to repeat the size all over:

```
int vv[] = { 12,43 };
std::vector<int> v(begin(vv), end(vv));
```

Comment: Or simply: std::vector<int> v(vv, vv+2);

Comment: Or more robustly: `std::vector<int> v(begin(w), end(w);`.  The `begin` and `end` are standard in C++11 (but then you don't need them), but should be in your tool kit otherwise.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but what exactly are you doing here: `std::vector<int> v(&vv[0], &vv[0]+2);` ? What I see is, you're constructing a vector with room for `&vv[0]` (which will be a memory address) values, and filling each space in the vector with `&vv[0]+2`... That would be using constructor 2 on this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector without supplying the third argument, which defaults to Allocator(). I know I'm missing something.

Comment: I think `std::vector<int> v(&vv[0], &vv[0]+2)` is invoking the 4th constructor on that page, actually. The constructor can take the first and last element in a range and create a vector with everything in between. The tipoff is the `&` will result in memory addresses.

Comment: What if I want to initialize an array on the heap?

Comment: @qed what do you think `vector` is?

Comment: I don't know, a data container?

Comment: And what's an array if not a data container, too?

Comment: @qed A vector *is* an array on the heap.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Cool. But how come we never delete a vector by hand?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes And if I do `vector<int> b {1, 2}`, is `b` then a pointer to a vector on the heap? Is that different from
`vector<int>* b = new vector<int>; b.push_back(1); b.push_back(2)`?

Comment: @qed We never delete vectors by hand because they have a destructor that automatically deletes the stuff on the heap, and the destructor is automatically called when the vector goes out of scope.

Comment: @qed Your second example has a bug. I think you mean `b->push_back(1);`. In the first example b is not a pointer, it is a object. The difference between those two examples is where the metadata (size and address of the main data) is stored. In the first example the size and address of the main data are stored on the stack. In the second example the size and address of the main data are stored on the heap. In both cases the main data itself is stored on the heap.

Comment: Which standard do you mean by `new`

Answer (score 32):

You can also do like this:

```
template <typename T>
class make_vector {
public:
  typedef make_vector<T> my_type;
  my_type& operator<< (const T& val) {
    data_.push_back(val);
    return *this;
  }
  operator std::vector<T>() const {
    return data_;
  }
private:
  std::vector<T> data_;
};
```

And use it like this:

```
std::vector<int> v = make_vector<int>() << 1 << 2 << 3;
```

Comment: Is it possible to move *data_* to *v* instead of calling the copy constructor?

Comment: Hello Per! I suppose you do like this (warning, untested): 
operator std::vector<T>&& () {
   return std::move(data_);
}