# vector initialization in vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, initialization, initializer-list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
class M {
    vector<string> s;
    public:
    M(){
        s = {"abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"};
    }
};

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

The code can be compiled in c9, but in vs2010, it can't be compiled successfully.why?

Comment: Check if VS 2010 supports C++ 11

Comment: `The code can be compiled in c9,`, no its C++ 11 feature

Comment: check out answers in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906545/how-to-initialize-a-vector-in-c

Answer (score 3):

MS VC++ 2010 does not support `std::initializer_list` as a parameter for member functions of standard containers.

Answer (score 1):

You may follow this,

```
static const string arrStr[] = {"abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"};
vector<string> s(arrStr, arrStr + sizeof(arrStr)/sizeof(arrStr[0]));
```