# Function that returns the max of a variable number of scalars

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, max

I need to create a function that takes as an input a variable number of scalars and returns the biggest one. Just like std::max() does for 2 elements, but I need it for an undefined number of elements, can be 2, or 5, or 10 etc.. Any suggestions on how to approach this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I tried with:

```
std::max({2, 8, 5, 3})
```

Error: no instance of overloaded function "std::max" matches the argument list

```
std::vector<int> v {2, 8, 5, 3};
```

Error: expected a ; (after v)

And more important, if I put this into a function, how do I have a variable number of arguments and how do I call them? I guess it should be somehow with a template?

What I need it for: I'm working with a bunch of vectors, maps, etc. and I need to find out which has the most elements. So I was thinking that I should end up with something like

```
int biggest = max(vector1.size(), vector2.size(), map1.size(), ...);
```

Comment: Try to use a C++11 compiler.

Comment: For the compile error:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906545/how-to-initialize-a-vector-in-c

Comment: As I remember VC2010 does not supported `initialize_lists`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [*`std::max_element`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element), if you have a container already populated

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::max_element( vector1.begin(), vector1.end() );
```

Else use plain array like following :

```
int a[] = {2, 8, 5, 3 }; // add whatever elements you want
int *pos = std::max_element( a, a+sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) ) ;
```

Comment: It looks like OP doesn't have C++11.

Comment: How do I have a variable number of arguments for the function and call them? So that I could have a for loop to push_back each argument into the vector

Comment: @POW I like the array version of returning the max better. But again, how do I turn it into a function with a variable number of arguments?

Comment: @KKO So since you want everything from SO, here you go
http://rextester.com/UGE11198, and please choose the one you want, thanks !

Comment: Thank you! I was just trying something like the first maxof. It's exactly what I need