# STL vector initialization with two arguments

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I saw [How to initialize a vector in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906545/how-to-initialize-a-vector-in-c) but couldn't find the same case so I ask here.

What is this expression? It's not two dimensional vector(I mean vector of vector). Is it declaring a vector with two elements?

```
vector<int> mult_dims(1, 2);
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: I hope to get no more negative votes.. :)

Comment: people should stop such negative voting behavior. everything question has its values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just read [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/).

```
explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val);
```

> **fill constructor:**
>   Constructs a container with n elements. Each element is a copy of val.

---

You code

```
 vector<int> mult_dims(1, 2);
```

Constructs a vector with *one* element with the value *2*.

It's equivalent to:

```
  std::vector<int> NO_mult_dims = {2};
```

Answer (score 0):

A multi dimensional vector is declared as a vector of vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> multi_dims{};
```

To initialize a vector with 2 elements, just do

```
std::vector<int> my_vec = { 1, 2 };
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;   //vector of vector for matrix
    vec.push_back({ 10,20,30 }); //first row 
    vec.push_back({ 11,22,33 });  // second row

    for (auto x : vec)                  //printing matrix
    { std::cout << x[0] << " " << x[1] << " "<<x[2]<<std::endl; }

    return 0;
}
```