# In C++ how to initialize a vector with values {1,2,...,n} without a loop?

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose n is a large integer, how to initialize a vector with {1,2,...,n} without a loop in C++? Thanks.

Comment: check out `std::iota`

Comment: Take a look at [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

Comment: @krzaq Huh what please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You can use `iota` to fill a sequence with incrementing values. It certainly looks like a better solution than an initializer list when *n is a large integer*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize a vector in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906545/how-to-initialize-a-vector-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
std::vector<int> v( 123 );
std::iota( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), 1 );
```

Comment: Problem here is that you initialize the vector in the first line, and then assign again numbers to it.

Answer (score 2):

If `N` is known at compile-time, you can define an helper function like this:

```
#include<utility>
#include<vector>

template<std::size_t... I>
auto gen(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::vector<std::size_t>{ I... };
}

int main() {
    auto vec = gen(std::make_index_sequence<3>());
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that (realistically) result in huge .rodata section?