# How to expand a pattern without parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Suppose I have the following function template:

```
int bar();

template <std::size_t... Is>
void foo()
{
    constexpr auto N = sizeof...(Is);
    int a[N] {/* magic here, like bar()... */};
}
```

I want to initialize the array `a` with `N` `bar()`s. The first solution I came up with is like the following:

```
int a[N] {(Is, bar())...};
```

But it results in some "expression result unused" warnings.

[LIVE EXAMPLE](https://godbolt.org/g/kJ68YM)

How can I get rid of these warnings if I don't want to turn off the `-Wunused-value` flag? Or is there any other way to write `N` `bar()`s? It is better that the solution works not only for `bar()`, but also for any expression that does not depend on `Is`.

---

Edit: the use of initializing an array is only an example. There are many other contexts that require such a sequence of expressions (for example, use for arguments of another template). So what I really want is how to generate such a sequence rather than to initialize the array.

Comment: When using C++ try and steer towards solutions that use containers like `std::vector` and away from those that use C-style arrays.

Comment: What about `((void)Is, bar())...`? An explicit cast to `void` expresses an explicit disinterest in a value.

Comment: @tadman `vector` cannot be used at compile time.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux OK, that's a nice answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906545/how-to-initialize-a-vector-in-c) count? Having a variable length initialization is problematic, but that's the crux of this question and applies equally to both C array and C++ solutions.

Comment: Do you need `bar()` to run N times? Does it have any side-effects?

Comment: @tadman, just nitpicking: The alternative to these kind of C-style arrays is `std::array`, not `std::vector`.

Comment: @andreee There's a bunch of containers available and each has their various benefits and drawbacks. `std::vector` is a good default in most cases. `std::array` might be better here, but as this thing isn't actually used in this trivial demonstration code, it's hard to say what the best fit really is.

Comment: @einpoklum Yes, it may have side-effects. If it has no side-effect, does the problem get simplified?

Comment: @xskxzr If `bar` has side effects, be sure that the order of evaluation doesn't matter. Notably, `bar` better always return the same thing for the duration of the initialization of a given `a`. Order of evaluation for operands is unspecified in c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is to silent the warning locally, as casting to `void`:

```
int a[N] {(static_cast<void>(Is), bar())...};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/hggBuJ)

Answer (score 3):

This solution requires two steps, but you could do something like initialize the array, then `std::fill_n` with values.

```
template <std::size_t... Is>
void foo()
{
    constexpr auto N = sizeof...(Is);
    int a[N];
    std::fill_n(a, N, bar());
}
```

Comment: Alternately `std::generate_n(a, N, bar)`, if the result of `bar` is expected to change, or isn't copyable

Comment: @Caleth: You should really make that an answer, since it's distinctly better.

Comment: @Caleth If `bar` is expected to change then the original example is at best unspecified behavior for `N > 1`. Though it would be more in line with the original intention, for example if `bar` had side effects such as counting the number of calls to it or something where the order of execution doesn't matter.