# How to directly use vector as parameter in a function?

Tags: c++, stl

I know how to initilize a new vector before using it, but how to convenitently use it as paramter in a function?
For example, when I init v1, it can get result in the end, but when I use v2, it shows error :cannot use this type name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Solution {
    public:
    vector<int> Add(vector<int>&nums, int target)
    {       
        cout << nums[0] + target;
    }
};

int main(){
    Solution Sol1;
    vector <int> v1 {1,2,3};
    Sol1.add(v1, 8);
    Sol1.add(vector <int> v2{4,5,6}, 8);
}
```

Besides, I tried to correct v2 as `Sol1.add(vector <int> {4,5,6}, 8);` However, it shows error: The initial value of a non-constant reference must be an left value

Comment: `Add` promises to return vector, but returns nothing. Never ignore compiler errors. C++ is a case sensitive language. You call `add`, but the class does not have such method. The line with `v2` is not correct.

Comment: on top of what S.M. mentioned if you remove v2 from the .Add(...) line and make nums a const ref it should work (you cannot bind temporaries to l-value refs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having has nothing to do with `vector`.

```cpp
Sol1.add(vector<int> v2{4,5,6}, 8);
```

Here, it seems like you are trying to declare an object name `v2` in the middle of this expression, which isn't something you can do in C++.

However, you can create a unnamed temporary object in the middle of it like:

```cpp
Sol1.add(vector<int>{4,5,6}, 8);
```

or even:

```cpp
Sol1.add({4,5,6}, 8);
```

But now you would face a different problem, like you mentioned:

> The initial value of a non-constant reference must be an left value

The reason for that is you can't create a reference to a temporary object. To solve it, you can either copy the `vector` to your function, by changing the signature of your `add` function:

```cpp
vector<int> add(vector<int> nums, int target)
{
  ⋮
}
```

However, this solution need to copy the entire `vector` to the function, hence it might be quite slow if your `vector` is large. Another way is to change the signature to const reference of a vector, which can bond to a temporary object. The downside is that you will not be able to modify the object inside the function, if you were looking to do that:

```cpp
vector<int> add(const vector<int>& nums, int target)
{
  ⋮
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the ways.
But in this way you will not be able use the variable `v2`

```
Sol1.add({4,5,6}, 8);
```

For more details read this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906545/how-to-initialize-a-vector-in-c)