# Initialising a vector of std::string with an array

Tags: c++, stl

I wish to initialise a vector using an array of `std::string`s.

I have the following solution, but wondered if there's a more elegant way of doing this?

```
std::string str[] = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
vector< std::string > vec;
vec = vector< std::string >( str, str + ( sizeof ( str ) /  sizeof ( std::string ) ) );
```

I could, of course, make this more readable by defining the size as follows:

```
int size =  ( sizeof ( str ) /  sizeof ( std::string ) );
```

and replacing the vector initialisation with:

```
vec = vector< std::string >( str, str + size );
```

But this still feels a little "inelegant".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231491/how-to-initialize-const-stdvectort-like-a-c-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the intermediate step isn't needed:

```
std::string str[] = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
vector< std::string > vec( str, str + ( sizeof ( str ) /  sizeof ( std::string ) ) );
```

In C++11 you'd be able to put the brace initialization in the constructor using the initializer list constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't certain whether I'd completely missed any other potential methods of initialising things.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, we have `std::begin` and `std::end`, which work for both STL-style containers and built-in arrays:

```
#include <iterator>

std::vector<std::string> vec(std::begin(str), std::end(str));
```

although, as mentioned in the comments, you usually won't need the intermediate array at all:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
```

In C++03, you could use a template to deduce the size of the array, either to implement your own `begin` and `end`, or to initialise the array directly:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
std::vector<T> make_vector(T &(array)[N]) {
    return std::vector<T>(array, array+N);
}

std::vector<std::string> vec = make_vector(str);
```

Comment: In C++11 we have proper initialisers, no need for the first of your methods.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: good point (although the question does specifically ask about initialising from an array, so I'll leave that method in the answer).

Comment: Long before C++11, we had `begin` and `end` in our personal tool kit.  And they're mostly relevant to pre-C++11.

Comment: Thanks for this. It doesn't quite fit into the code I'm currently working on, but it is good to know. I should also have stated that I am not using C++11, but again, thank you for your help!