# Assigning a vector from an array (pointer)

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a standard way to accomplish this that is better than a `for` loop?

If I had an array type [supposedly](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t282217-can-i-assign-safely-an-array-to-vector.html) I can do this:

```
double d_array[] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
std::vector<double> d_vector(d_array, d_array+3);
```

But I can't do this when I only have a `double *` and an `int` indicating its length.

Edit: Actually, I think I actually can do this. The error messages are quite a handful, though, if you get your type parameters wrong (which is why it didn't work for me at first).

Comment: Have you tried it? Can you show it to us?

Comment: It seems to work now. When trying to do this with mis-matched types the error messages are incredibly verbose although not entirely cryptic.

Comment: You might wanna look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231491/how-to-initialize-const-stdvectort-like-a-c-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can do it the same way

```
int length;
double *d;
//allocate memory and data to pointer
std::vector<double> d_vector(d, d+length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep. You should be able to do this. The relevant constructor is `template <class InputIterator> vector ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const Allocator& = Allocator() );` - and pointers are iterators too (since you can do integer arithmetic on them).

That being said, all that the vector is doing is iterating over the elements of `d_array`, so don't expect the performance to be significantly better than the `for` loop version.

Comment: It's really quite cool that it's able to transparently use pointers like this. That this **could** in any way have better performance than the for loop version is incredible (though not really of course because a naive for loop would cause the vector to resize itself). Anyway, I like things like this because it helps cuts down on bugs.

Comment: It may be smart enough to subtract the two pointers to find out how many values it'll be looping over, and allocate enough space for them initially.  Default-constructing a vector and inserting the values yourself may require it to reallocate as the vector grows.

Comment: Right, in my naive implementation I needed to figure out whether i wanted to use `resize` or `reserve`... Using the ctor or `assign` with pointers is just so much neater.

Comment: It's possible it might be smart enough to do a pre-allocation, but it's not guaranteed that it can even make an educated guess. It just takes an InputIterator, and for those there's no guarantee that the iteration is contiguous. You can create an InputIterator that jumps ahead an arbitrary amount - say, 4 * sizeof(double), whatever you want - though it would certainly be possible to optimize, it's a lot of special casing to do so. (though, if I were implementing the standard, I would make that "guess" by pre-allocating the delta and trusting it to resize if my guess was wrong...)