# C++: How to make a vector that already contains elements

Tags: c++, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [C++: Easiest way to initialize an STL vector with hardcoded elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/c-easiest-way-to-initialize-an-stl-vector-with-hardcoded-elements)
> [How to initialize a vector in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906545/how-to-initialize-a-vector-in-c)

I was wondering if there's a way to make a vector with announced elements..

Instead of having to do:

```
vector< int > v;  
v.push_back(3);  
v.push_back(5);  
v.push_back(1);
```

and etc, where `v = {3,5,1}`,

I want to make a vector that already contains elements like:

```
vector< int > v = {3,5,1};
```

Because it is a lot of work inserting each number in the vector. Is there a shortcut to this?

Comment: here is another : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/c-easiest-way-to-initialize-an-stl-vector-with-hardcoded-elements/2239749#2239749

Answer (score 13):

C++11 supports exactly the syntax you suggest:

```
vector< int > v = {3,5,1};
```

This feature is called [uniform initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization).

There isn't any "nice" way to do this in previous versions of the language.

Comment: There are also some alternatives using the copy ctor and boost/assign template lib, as per this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231491/how-to-initialize-const-stdvectort-like-a-c-array

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`boost::assign`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html)

```
std::vector<int> v = boost::assign::list_of(3)(5)(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do in C++11

```
std::vector< int > v = {3,5,1};
```

as Greg Hewgill suggessted or in C++98

```
static const int v_[] = {3,5,1};
std::vector<int> vec (v_, v_ + sizeof(v_) / sizeof(v_[0]) );
```

compliments to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2236227/1276982

Answer (score 2):

Yes in C++11 you can do

```
std::vector<int> v { 1,2,3,4 };
```

you can create multiple elements of the same value through the constructor in C++98

```
std::vector<int> v (5, 6); //6 6 6 6 6
```

if you don't have C++11 you can create some sort of push back object

```
#include <vector>

struct pb{
    std::vector<int>& v_;  

    pb(std::vector<int>& v) 
    : v_(v){}; 

    pb& operator+(int i) {
        v_.push_back(i);
        return *this;  
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> d;
    pb(d)+4+3; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++11 has such a feature, most compilers support it.

To enable in gcc:

```
    g++ -std=gnu++0x
```

VS2010 supports it out of the box I think