# std::vector, why initializer list does not work in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, visual-c++, vector, c++-cli, initializer-list

Three simple statements, one does not compile.

```
std::vector<size_t>({});
std::vector<size_t>({ 1 });  // This does not compile
std::vector<size_t>({ 1, 2 });
```

Only the second statement with one element in the list brings an error:

```
cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'std::vector<size_t,std::allocator<char32_t>>'
```

It works fine for `char`, `long`, `int` etc., but not for `size_t`. Does anybody know why and maybe there is a workaround?

Here is the complete code:

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    std::vector<size_t>({});
    std::vector<size_t>({ 1 });
    std::vector<size_t>({ 1, 2 });
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the C++/CLI compiler from VS2013

Comment: [Works fo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b360341326a33bcf)[r me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9fb491f977996f3). Where is your [MCVE]?

Comment: Works since c++11.

Comment: Why are you using a size_t as template argument? Wouldn't you use a int or a long?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-to initialize 'const std::vector<T>' like a c array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231491/how-to-initialize-const-stdvectort-like-a-c-array)

Comment: @sergiol: Why would you use `int` or `long` when `size_t` is appropriate?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Normally that's not the case.

Comment: @Klaus We really need an [mcve] before we can say what the issue is.

Comment: @sergiol: According to what?

Comment: @Wernfried what version of c++ are you using? If you don't know, what's the compiler version? If you don't know *that*, what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I'm going to put money on the issue being the OP is not using C++11.  The error states *'initializer-list'* which is not the same as a `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Here is the complete program, just the three lines

Comment: @Wernfried There is a [edit] link on your question you can use to edit the code into the question.  Also what compiler are you using?

Comment: You might want to add the [tag:c++-cli] tag to this, @Wernfried.

Comment: In ISO C++ the initializations are correct and use the `initializer_list<size_t>` constructor of vector. obviously C++/CLI is different

Comment: There are various kinds of miracles required to get a language extension that was frozen 11 years ago to compile C++11 code.  Nevertheless, it works just fine in VS2015.  Sure, not in  VS2013, work in progress, @Guillaume gives the workaround.  Do use the System::Collections::Generic namespace instead so you don't get the worst of both worlds.  `List<T>` is a better `vector<T>`

Answer (score 1):

The right and proper way to use std::initializer-list is

```
    std::vector<size_t>{};
    std::vector<size_t>{ 1 };
    std::vector<size_t>{ 1, 2 };
```

Ie. Without parenthesis. See http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#init-list for examples.

Using this should fix your issue. Otherwise, in last resort, you can force type like this: `std::vector<size_t>( std::initializer-list<size_t>{ 1 } );`